# Radio Button no C#

Tags: c#, radiobutton

Olá, possuo uma tela de cadastro e salva tudo ok de acordo com os dados preenchidos, porém quando clico no botao alterar retorna todos os valores cadastros, mas não retorna radio button selecionado conforme que foi cadastrado na hora da inclusão.

Ou seja, quando clico no botao alterar e deve retornar radio button selecionado c#.

Como faço?

```
if (CodTaxa > 0)
{
    objTaxa = TaxaBo.getByID(CodTaxa);
    objTaxa.DESCRICAO = txtEditDescricao.Text;
    objTaxa.TIPOVALOR = tipoValor.ToString(); //valor atribuido pelo radio button
    objTaxa.REC_DESP = operacao;//valor atribuido pelo radio button
    objTaxa.VLRPADRAO = Convert.ToDecimal(txtEditValorPadrao.Text);

    if(ValidaCampos())
    { 
        TaxaBo.Alterar(objTaxa);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Algum campo precisa ser preenchido", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código de como você carrega os dados na tela, pois sem o código é difícil de saber, pode ser algum erro de binding do componente.

Comment: Além do binding, talvez, não esteja atribuindo valor à propriedade Checked.

Comment: já está ai!!!!! Existe alguma propriedade ou metodo para colocar como atribuição no REC_DESP?

Comment: Cadê a parte do código que você preenche os componentes com as informações do objeto?

Comment: Para que seu radio button esteja marcado como falou comentou, a propriedade Checked tem que ser setada(receber valor: True ou False em binário seria 0 ou 1). Nesse código postado não está claro onde você está realizando essa operação.

Answer (score 1):

Assim você conseguirá fazer a validação e conseguirá exibir a informação...

```
 //Radio Button Checked
        if (rbY.Checked)
        {
            Model.Tipo_Id = 1;
        }
        if (rbZ.Checked)
        {
            Model.Tipo_Id = 2;
        }
```

Este Tipo_Id é onde está salvo as opções do Radio